# How do I tell (*Neovim*) that `.ipynb` files have 1 space indents, so indent guides are correctly shown?

Tags: neovim, indentation

I'm using the *Indent Blankline* plugin to show indent guides.

My *Jupyter Notebook*/`.ipynb` files have 1 space indents. *Vim* identifies them as *JSON* files.

One way to tell *Neovim* that *Jupyter Notebook* files have 1 space indents, is to just create `~/.config/nvim/ftplugin/json.lua`.

But I still want *JSON* files to have 2 space indents.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could introduce a new file type for the `*.ipynb` file (jupyter) by introducing a `~/.config/nvim/ftdetect/jupyter.vim` or `~/.config/nvim/ftdetect/jupyter.lua` file:

`ftdetect/jupyter.vim`:

```
autocmd BufReaf,BufNew *.ipynb setfiletype jupyter
```

Or in
`ftdetect/jupyter.lua`:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({'BufRead', 'BufNew'}, {
  pattern = '*.ipynb',
  command = 'setfiletype jupyter'
})
```

With that new filetype you could have your specific `jupyter` configuration in:
`ftplugin/jupyter.lua`

```
vim.o.tabstop = 1
vim.o.shiftwidth = 1
```

With this solution you have full control but you lose some of the configuration settings you have with the `python` file type.

Another solution is to override the configuration by adding in your `init.lua` some autocmd to set settings you want for that file pattern:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({'BufRead', 'BufNew'}, {
  pattern = '*.ipynb',
  command = ":set expandtab tabstop=1 shiftwidth=1"
})
```

Comment: Thanks. I got it working with some slight modifications. I renamed `autocmd()` to `vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd()`, as the former wasn't recognized. I couldn't manage to create a new file type based on the *JSON* type using *Lua*. I use *Tree-sitter*, if that matters. Do you mind expanding on that?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback (and sorry for the wrong shortcut). I have expanded the `new filetype` section. Let me know if you need more information.